# Chrome 42 gets stuck in "pending" while loading image

Tags: google-chrome

I am having a strange issue with Chrome 42 (Version 42.0.2311.135 m). Running a normal instance side by side with an icognito instance, the normal instance sometimes hangs while loading an image (I've tried with svg and png). The instance gets strangely stuck in the sense that it doesn't ever try to load images again - even when I reload the page. Some WebSocket requests I have going continue to work - but never more images.

The only way to bring chrome back to normal is to close the tab and relaunch it.

The site I am debugging runs locally on IIS 8 from Visual Studio 2013 and is a C# asp.net mvc site.

**Edit**

I made a little screencast that shows the bug:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToTFfkYw-4s&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

It turned out that most likely this is a Chromium bug that is only appearing when running an extension that modifies host headers. Requestly is my favorite. I did some discussion together with the developer of Requestly. Read here: 
https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/issues/52

I ended up posting a Chromium issue here: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490027

Comment: I'm having also samithing strange with Chrome 42. Mine is loads forever most sites. I've open de developer console in the network and I can confirm that it loads forever....

Comment: I changed the content expiration of the site to make the client cache static files for a day at a time, so now the problem happens only once in a while. It seems to be connected to the caching.

Comment: I've the same problem with Chrome Version 45.0.2454.93 m. It pends images sometimes: not always. Once this occured, the used tab never loads neither this image, nor other images from the same web server. But it can restart work for another web site of another domain. This is the case even if disactivated all extensions. The image loads if one loads the image in another tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a Chromium bug. I've filed an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490027

Here is a Github repository with instructions on how to reproduce the bug: 
https://github.com/nitech/chrome-header-extension-bug